# Are we using Abel's theorem here?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

We can show by using the geometric series that $$\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}, \forall x \in (-1, 1).$$
Now, we know that the series in the RHS converges when $x=\pm 1$ (by the Leibniz test for instance), so we may write that $$\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}, \forall x \in [-1, 1].$$
My qustion is whether this last equality is due to Abel's theorem. I think that it is, but I just want to make sure because the statement of Abel's theorem puzzles me sometimes.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: No worries, it happens to all of us :)

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Abels's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) explicitly answers your question.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2):

In general, suppose $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges for all $x \in (-1,1)$. If by some other means you show that  the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (-1)^n$ converge, then by defining $f$ appropriately you can always write that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

What Abel's theorem really provides is that $f$ defined in this way is **continuous** at the endpoints, that is

$$\lim_{x \to 1-} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n, \quad \lim_{x \to -1+} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(-1)^n$$

In this case, $f(x) = \arctan x$.